# Sending xsd Date over WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, datetime, date, xsd

We currently use DateTime in our WCF contracts. This results in data being sent over as XSD DateTime.

We have a requirement that when sending to a Java system that we send over a XSD Date and not a DateTime.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First hit on Google shows me this [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=182960) project, where they've written a WcfDate class that encapsulates (de)serializing from and to a `xsd:date` object.